# JNI Java-to-C++ call works when built in Eclipse, but not when built via command line

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, java-native-interface, static-libraries

The function calls are implemented in an .so file. When I build from command line, I get UnsatisfiedLinkError when the code attempts to call the native functions from Java (C-to-Java works correctly). The strangest part is that, when I externed the calls and obtained a pointer to them, the pointers are valid, then the UnsatisfiedLinkError still happens.

I guess the main question is, what does Eclipse do that command line doesn't (or vice versa)? I am at a loss, and need to get this working because other developers and the build server are incapable of building via Eclipse.

Another question would be, how does the function get found and called when using this mechanism (in Android)? I read a little bit of information on this, but nothing that helped me work out this problem.

Since it works within Eclipse, I am confident my JNI naming conventions are correct.

I have looked online quite extensively, but can't seem to get a good answer for this.

FYI, the .so file is included in the APK files (which look almost identical), and it is the only .so file.

Answer (score 1):

How do you compile your `.so` files? Do you pass the `-fvisibility=hidden` flag to g++ (provided that you use g++ for compiling)? And `-fPIC`?